# a and &a differs for an array passed as a function parameter in C

Tags: c, arrays

Why do the values of a and &a differ for a array passed as a function parameter? b and &b do not differ for an array defined within a function body. The code follows:

```
void foo(int a[2])
{
   int b[2];    
   printf("%p %p\n", a, &a);
   printf("%p %p\n", b, &b);
}

int main()
{
   int a[2];
   foo(a);  
   return 0;
}
```

EDIT:
So, after all the discussion, I understand the following is happening:

In `main()`:

```
int a[2]; /* define an array. */
foo(a);   /* 'a' decays into a pointer to a[0] of type (int*). */
          /* since C is pass-by-value, this pointer is replicated and */
          /* a local copy of it is stored on the stack for use by foo(). */
```

In `foo()`:

```
printf("%p %p\n", a, &a); /* 'a' is the value of the pointer that has been replicated, */
                          /* and it points to 'a[0]' in main() */
                          /* '&a' is the address of the replicated pointer on the stack. */
                          /* since the stack grows from higher to lower addresses, */
                          /* the value of '&a' is always lower than a. */
```

Comment: @nitzs nice question.Do you mean that in your code you can't call foo() as foo(&a).

Comment: @Algorithmist: While I don't think that is what the question means, the fact is that you cannot, as the types will not match. Inside `main`, `a` decays into `&a[0]`, which is of type `int*`, while `&a` is of type `int (*)[2]`.

Comment: @Algorithmist, Wouldn't (&a) decay into into a similar pointer?

Comment: @nitzs when i ran above code with foo(&a) it worked.But @david is an expert so he must be definitely right.

Comment: @nitzs @david i think we can make ot the diffeence when we take array in function definition as 2D array.As @david said &a wuld be converted to int(*)[2] i.e pointer to a 1D array comprising of 2 elements.

Comment: @Algorithmist: my best advice is not to trust anyone for their reputation or you will be fooled many a time. As you did: ask for an explanation or a quote from the standard. When using `&a` as argument to `foo` in the question above, you should get a warning from the compiler saying that you are converting from incompatible pointer types.

Comment: @Algorighmist: I don't quite follow your last comment. If you define a 2D array as `int array2d[2][2];`, then `&array2d` will be `int (*)[2][2]`, while `array2d` will decay in most use cases to `int (*)[2]`, which is basically the same effect as the original example substituting `int` with `typedef int int2[2];`: `int2 array2d[2]`.

Comment: Another possibly surprising effect of the prototype transformation: In `foo`, `sizeof(a) != sizeof(b)`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Basically when you type `void foo( int a[2] )` you are writting in a funny way `void foo( int *a )`.

I would have to look for the particular quote from the standard, but when a function signatures are being analyzed, an argument of type *array of N elements of type T* is converted to *pointer to T*. When you later type `foo(a)`, `a` decays into a pointer to the address of the first element, which is copied. Inside `foo` you are comparing the value of a pointer to first element of the array `a` in `main` with the address of the pointer `a` in `foo`.

On the other hand, within the same function, when the array is within scope as `b` inside `foo`, the address of the array (`&b`) and the address of the first element of the array (which can be obtained by forcing the decay by typing `b`) are the same address.

Two simple pieces of information for the future:

- arrays in function signatures are interpreted as pointers: avoid that syntax and use the pointer syntax, you will get less surprises
- identifiers that denote an array decay into a pointer to the first element in most contexts

Example:

```
void foo( int a[2] ); // void foo( int *a );
int main() {
   int x[2];
   foo( x );         // foo( &x[0] ); -- inside foo, a is a copy of &x[0]
   printf( "%d\n%d\n", (int)&a, (int)a ); // &a[0] which is the same address as &a
                                          // (different type though)
}
```

Comment: @nitzs: I have updated the answer, if you need a further explanation I can try to rewrite it, or clear any particular doubt

Comment: when i call the foo(&a) and foo(a) i don't find any subtle difference in their o/p.Could you please sight an example where we can distinguish between &a and a (wher a is the array name) in any function call in terms of output.

Comment: @Algorithmist: `void foo( int* ) {} int main() { int a[2]; foo(&a); printf( "%d != %d\n", sizeof(*a), sizeof(*(&a)) ); }`. That will give you one warning on invalid pointer type conversion when calling `foo` (probably other warnings in the printf) and the output of running the program will contain two different numbers the second of which is twice the value of the first (probably "4 != 8")

Answer (score 3):

An array is not a pointer. It evaluates to a pointer in almost all context, but one of the notable exceptions is the `&` operator.

So if you call a function with an array as a parameter

```
f(a);
```

the `a` there evaluates to the address of the first element `&(a[0])` that is passed to the function.

If you use `&a` the address of the array as a whole is taken. It has the same value as `&(a[0])` but the type is different. `&(a[0])` has type *"pointer to basetype"* whereas `&a` has type *"pointer to array of basetype"*.

Inside the function `&a` is something different. Here `a` is a *"pointer to basetype"* so `&a` is of type *"pointer to pointer to basetype"* and the address that you see is the address of the pointer on the stack and not of your original array.

Answer (score 2):

When you pass a parameter by reference to a function, you technically put an address of the element into function call stack. When you use `&` with function parameter , you get the address of that value. I'll try to illustrate it (all addresses are arbitrary, for demonstration only):

```
int main()
{
   int a[2] ; //  a == &a == 0x001234 
   foo(a); // address of a (0x001234) goes to call stack, 
   // this value is stored in 0x00122C 
   // now inside foo(), &a  == 0x00122C , a == 0x001234


}
```

Comment: you mean to say that &a would differ inside and outside the function.

Comment: It's a bit confusing here because `a` - is the name of formal and actual argument. To clarify, it's probably better to use a different name for actual argument : ` int b[2]; foo(b)` - here we pass `b` to the function. Within function body it's accessible trough formal parameter `a`. So `&a != &b`.